# What are the Linux hibernation feature threats?

Tags: linux

The pre-built hardened linux kernel proposed by ArchLinux has disabled hibernation. [The maintainer of the package commented on this choice](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/63648):

> […] having this enabled allows replacement of the running kernel given certain circumstances and access as it suspends the state to disc.

What are the *"certain circumstances"* he is talking about? Is it just about manipulation/extraction of the state on the disk if someone has physical access to the disk? Is encryption enough to prevent this kind of attack?

Is there any other threat I should be aware of, if I chose to build my kernel with hibernation enabled, or if I use hibernation?

Comment: There's also the issue of simply writing the memory to disk will allow an attacker to potentially recover secrets by reading the drive / hibernation file.

Comment: @user Yes you are right, that's what I'm calling "manipulation/extraction of the state on the disk". I am not sure if it is safe even with encryption (or if it defeats — or is incompatible with — some of the other security measures used in this hardened config). It could explain why hibernation is not enabled.